# jQuery change CSS background position and mouseover/mouseout

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a menu composed of a single image (e.g., sprites). In order to display the hover image, I simply move the background image down. I'd like this effect to be controlled by jQuery and animated.

This is a sample menu item.

```
 <ul>
  <li id="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

This is what I'm toying with. I'm very new to jQuery and am having problems getting the proper selector going.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#home a');

   // Set the 'normal' state background position
   .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )

   // On mouse over, move the background
   .mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"}, {duration:500})
   })

   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:500})
   })

 });
```

Could you point out what I'm doing wrong? I know the selector is probably incorrect but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to manipulate the anchor.

Comment: What exactly is happening or not happening?

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the $('#home a') selector.  Does that fix it?

Comment: @Pekka, basically, nothing is happening. The background does not show up which makes me believe that the selector is wrong.


@ryanulit, added the semi-colon. Unfortunately, no change.

Comment: Why did you add a semicolon to `$('#home a')`? That is definitely wrong, and cuts off the chained commands that follow.

Comment: Are we sure that "background-position" is something that jQuery can animate? I don't use "animate()" much but from looking at the code and reading the docs, it seems like it really wants to work with things like "height" and "width" that have a single numeric value. (Also, it seems to me that animating a transition between sprites would be kind-of weird in general, but I don't know what these sprites look like of course.)

Comment: @Pekka, I'm sure you're right about the semi-colon. I'm having a hard time following jQuery's syntax. I'm only on day two, so do let me know if I'm doing it wrong. ;)

Comment: @Pointy that's why I'm for using background-animation-x/y, that is the combination that still has the best chance of getting animated, if there is support for it at all.

Comment: @steelfrog you're not the only one :) I accept jQuery as the best JS framework around, but the syntax really looks like crap. It's absolutely horrible bracket soup to me.

Comment: @Pointy, I've seen "background-position" be animated before in a tutorial somewhere. It's actually a pretty nifty way to avoid using Flash for simpler stuff. The sprites are appropriate for this.

Comment: @Pekka I think you mean "background-position-x" and "background-position-y", but those are IE-only I think.

Comment: @Pointy Of course! Time for lunch break :) Removed the comment.

Comment: @Pekka and @steelfrog, sorry if that wasn't clear about the semicolon.  I meant add it at the VERY end at the end of the mouseout function.

Comment: @ryanulit, not a problem. I'm learning as I go. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you were not animating the transitions — and given the kinds of images I've grouped as sprites, I don't know why you'd ever do that — then you'd want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#home a')
    // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 -54px');
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function() {
     $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
   })
 });
```

Now, if you *are* trying to animate that, then you've got bad syntax for the CSS and for the calls to "animate".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#home a')
   // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 -54px"}, 500);
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"}, 500);
   })
 });
```

Again, I am doubtful that jQuery is going to be able to animate "backgroundPosition" for you, but then I don't do "animate()" very often and jQuery always manages to surprise me.

**edit:** here's a page: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

Comment: That's the one I was looking at! Your second snippet fixed everything. I was also missing the plugin, which resolved the rest. Thank you!

Comment: Oh goodie, I'm glad it worked. I'll have to look at the plugin because now I'm curious about the sort of things one might do with that :-)

Comment: yeah you sure need this plugin - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect cheers!

Answer (score 3):

> {backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"

(You don't want the brackets there. There's no brackets in a CSS `background-position` rule.)

In any case jQuery doesn't know how to animate a compound value like `backgroundPosition`. In IE you get access to it with `backgroundPositionY`, which, as a simple value, jQuery *can* animate. However this is non-standard and won't work elsewhere.

[Here's a plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/) that claims to fix it.

Comment: Yes I think that's referenced by that page I linked to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

i liked this method (just css)

```
.maintopbanner a:hover{
    background-position: -200px 0 !important;}
.maintopbanner a {
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine your background is bound to the `li`?! However `this` is set to the `a` of the selector, so if my assumption is correct you would need to change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#home a')

   // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"}, {duration:500})
   })

   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, {duration:500})
   })

 });
```

Comment: The background is in fact set on the anchor due to a limitation in IE6. I wish I could simply set it to the list item but it would completely break in IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
         $('#home a')
.mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 -54px)"},500)
       })
.mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},500)
       })
```

//Use MouseEnter and MouseLeave whenever possible and you do not need to type out duration with the current version of jQuery. Hope this helps.