# how to change the background position of an element upon clicking a button

Tags: jquery

OK. I know this topic has been covered a hundred times. And I've tried everything for the last couple hours. . . and actually for the last few days. I'm pissed right now. So fine, whatever. I'll just ask for help.

Simple task. Click a button to change the position of the object.
(I want to actually be able to click a button and then scatter all the list items in a list about the page... but I feel once I figure out how to do this simple task, I can just figure it out from there.

I honestly have tried EVERYTHING, every variation of code I saw online. I don't know why it's not working for me, but I think it must be because I'm messing up the syntax.

```
<p> I want to move this text </p>
<input type = "button" value = "Click me">

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(':button').click(function() { 
    $('p').css({backgroundPosition: '100px 0px'});
});
</script>
```

I tried removing the curly braces. I tried other variations including:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(':button').click(function() { 
$('p').css('backgroundPosition', '-100px 0px');
});
</script>
```

Countless hours looking on here and other places just to solve this simple problem.

All I want is the f'ing syntax. I can change background color easily, but position has two coordinates to change, and I don't know why none of the things I've tried worked.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: could you put this on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: refer this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515423/jquery-change-css-background-position-and-mouseover-mouseout

Comment: are you trying to move the text or some background image?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is not in your jQuery, that code is correct.  The problem appears to be in your css properties.  Consider the following variation on your code.

```
$(':button').click(function() { 
    $('p').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
});
```

Here i've changed the CSS to update the background color vs. position.  This works just fine and is demonstrated in the following fiddle

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7TuVx/

I would apply the CSS directly to the `p` object and see what you need to get it to move to the proper position, then update your jQuery code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(':button').click(function() { 
        $('p').css('background-position', '-100px 0px');
    });
</script>
```

You misspelled the css property.

Answer (score 0):

`backgroundPosition` refers to the position of an image set as the element's background. Changing that will not move your `<p>` tag. To move the element you should be modying `left` and `top`, but you also need to set `position` to relative or absolute.

Comment: This is what I ended up using.

    $(':button').click(function() {
 $("p").offset({ top: 100, left: 30 });
    });

Yeah, it's not the background-position I was after. What I really wanted to modify was the element's left and top properties. So it wasn't syntax that was the problem... it was the property itself. No wonder!